# xna .ElapsedGameTime is always the same, even if the programm laggs

Tags: c#, xna

I was wondering about .ElapsedGameTime in xna. I already read over half a dozend questions to this, which didn't answer what I was wondering about:
If the programm lags (and trust me, I did get my game to lag quite a bit) there should be more time between the updates, no? Regardless of beeing in the menu or having a frame rate of one frame every several seconds, .ElapsedGameTime always equals to 00:00:00.0166667
Why is that?

Comment: Is `IsFixedTimeStep` set to true? .0166667 per frame is ~60 frames per second.  It could also be related to vsync.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/2007/07/25/understanding-gametime/

Comment: It it set to the default, which should be true, yes. I read the article, thanks for that! Now I could test and confirm that even if `IsRunningSlowly` outputs true, .ElapsedGameTime is still the same - which is odd..
Either it stopps the update and starts a new one after exactly .0166667s, or it's simply lying to me! I can't explain it any other way

Comment: My guess, is that it is falling in to the 3rd option of "give up trying to correct timing issues" from the blog post.  Everything I've written so far sets `IsFixedTimeStep` to `false`, so I don't have any direct experience with what you are seeing.  From what I *have* seen in other posts, it is most likely that XNA is lying to you about the elapsed time between frames; it *always* reports 1/60 of a second in that mode.

Comment: I now tested it with `IsFixedTimeStep = false` and I found that the time now does change. Altough it nerver exceeds 0.2s per frame. I reach that number with some dozends of entities and with over a thousand it still doesn't exceed this.     
What exactly is "give up trying" supposed to mean? Does it just stop the update cycle and start the new one?

Comment: It only "gives up" in fixed time step mode.  When it is set to false, it never gives up, it doesn't do anything special and just calls Update -> Draw, over and over again, as fast as it can. Gametime *should* be an accurate measurement of the time from the previous update to the current update in that situation.

Comment: My interpretation of "give up" in fixed tiem step mode, is that XNA sees that last update was too long ago (not sure what the exact criteria is), and just calls update, telling it that 1/60th of a second elapsed, then draw.  It sort of like it just pretends that everything is running optimally, even though the game its self is probably stuttering like crazy.

Comment: Can I see the exact code you are using to display `ElapsedGameTime`?

Comment: I did more testing and as it turns out, I could not get it to exceed 0.5s per frame. Even if I tripple the stress, the ElapsedGameTime stays at excatly 00:00:00.5000000 .  I do beliefe that with it set to false, gameTime is an accurate measure - at least up to this point.
     What do you mean what code? I put it into a Console.WriteLine:  `Console.WriteLine(gameTime.IsRunningSlowly + "  " + gameTime.ElapsedGameTime);`

That is an interessting theory, you could very likely be right about this

Comment: Just keep in mind that in non fixed time step mode, you have to adjust everything based on ElapsedGameTime.  The usual method is to state everything in terms of units per second.  So when moving, you would  do something like `position += MovementSpeed * ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds`, instead of just adding `MovementSpeed` every frame.

Comment: I really don't understand why you can't get higher numbers in non fix time step mode.  I know I've personally seen >3 second frames when I've screwed something up.  What happens if you explicitly sleep for say, 3000ms at the very end of `Update`?

Comment: Good point, thanks, I'll keep it in mind.    
 How would you suggest letting it sleep? With `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);` it will sleep for 3s fer update call, but the gameTime ignores it - or better to say even though we're waiting for three seconds, the output still insists only 0.5s passed. Same for TotalGameTime, it is only increased by 0.5s per update call

Comment: Try sleeping in `Draw`.  I *thought* `ElapsedGameTime` included the running time of the last update too, but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: Nothing changed, even though I let it sleep in both of them - it's still at 0.5.. Well, let's just call it the border of the possible, as long as the player doesn't try very hard to break my game no one will ever reach this limit anyway. Thanks for your help, I did learn quite a lot!